# HDD stopped showing up & can't enter BIOS

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bios, cmos, adobe-lightroom

I have one 1TB HDD and one SSD on my PC. OS: Win10. About a month ago I bought another HDD, WD Purple 4TB, set everything up, formatted it, everything was okay until now.

I copied photos on this new HDD, everything looked okay. I imported photos into Lightroom, Lightroom showed me warning that 3 photos weren't imported because they may be corrupted or something but I just clicked okay and started editing photos after I edited about 3 photos and it took way too long for other photos to load, everything was slow, so I restarted my PC and when it came back on my new WD Purple HDD wasn't showing up. It's not in device management nor in disk management. I tried to uplug and plug cables, tried different cables and ports, nothing helps.

I tried to enter BIOS to see if it's in there, but when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> as it says on the loading screen, nothing happens, PC is frozen and the loading screen stays there forever. I tried this many times, always the same. Tried to clear CMOS by pushing the button on my motherboard, didn't help. I removed the battery from CMOS, put it back in after about 1.5 hours, nothing changes.

I also tried uninstalling the newest windows updates, didn't help.

I have no idea what to do. HDD doesn't seem to be making any strange noises or anything, I can hear the HDD platter start spinning when I turn on my PC and it slows down the spinning after a while so I suppose it's working.

If you have any idea what should I do, please help. Thank you.

Comment: First step, change the SATA cable & port it's connected to on the mobo. Don't put any pressure on the cable; test it with the computer cover off if there's any chance anything at all could be leaning on the cable. Those sockets are horribly delicate & pressure-sensitive.

Comment: Get the WD Bootable diagnostic disk (https://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?p=2), set it up and test the hard drive with it

Answer (score 0):

Changing the SATA cable is good advice.
If nothing works try connecting the hard drive in an external USB case for hard drives.
Some times this way you can recover Hard drives that are not visible to the system due to Hardware problems.
If this works, copy your Data to somewhere safe as the drive may not last long.